# Fit my tabs height in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Currently I have a few navigation `<nav>` tags. I have place the nav tag within a container with 100% width. But when I set the container height by a certain percentage the `<ul>` & `<li>` tag in the `nav` when click got cut off instead of scale down. How do I go about doing it?

here's my css code;

```
#container
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

below is my source code.

http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/107/

Comment: Can you add min-height instead of height? and check if it solves your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
height: 50%
```

can you just use

```
min-height: 50%
```

as this implies that the `min-height` will be 50% but **it will not restrict it in case container has huge content** that will be more that 50% height of the container

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/109/

Answer (score 0):

Percentage is applied to whatever default height the browser sets for the page.

So If by 50% you mean the **#container** to be 50% of the page height then you must have this as well:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```